# Unable to find events being raised when log file changed

Tags: .net, powershell, logging, events, filesystemwatcher

Im trying to use `FileSystemWatcher` to watch a file and check for changes, when a change occurs it should run aa command, this works when im saving the file in notepad, however not from the actual application that is making the log file.
Ive seen posts in the past saying that it may be due to the application creating a copy of the log with the new data added then deletes the original and renames the copy, so I tried looking for delete, creation and rename events and still nothing.

This is the class that I've been using, it does have to be a derived class of `FileSystemWatcher` as there is other functionality that is to be included which is out of the scope of this question.

```
class LogWatcher : System.IO.FileSystemWatcher {
    [System.Management.Automation.Job[]] $Event
    [string] $LogName = 'Endpointlog.txt'
    [string] $LogFolder = ('C:\Users\' + $env:USERNAME + '\AppData\Roaming\<pathtologfolder>')
    LogWatcher () : base($this.LogFolder, $this.LogName) {
        $this.Event = (new-object System.Management.Automation.Job[] 4)
        $this.EnableRaisingEvents = $true;
        $fsaction = {
            param ( 
                [System.Object] $sender,
                [System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs] $e
            )
            $sender | fl
            $e | fl
        }
        $rnaction = {
            param ( 
                [System.Object] $sender,
                [System.IO.renamedEventArgs] $e
            )
            $sender | fl
            $e | fl
        }
        $this.NotifyFilter =[System.IO.NotifyFilters]::Attributes, [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::CreationTime,     [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::DirectoryName, [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName, [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::LastAccess, [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite, [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::Security, [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::Size 
        $this.Event[0] = register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $this -EventName changed -Action $fsaction
        $this.Event[1] = register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $this -EventName created -Action $fsaction
        $this.Event[2] = register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $this -EventName deleted -Action $fsaction
        $this.Event[3] = register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $this -EventName renamed -Action $rnaction
    }
}
```

And initialising it as.
`$lw = [LogWatcher]::new();`

The log file is updated every couple seconds so I would expect that `$lw.Event` to show at least one `Job` that is running and not `Not Started` however I can still only get one `Job` to change and that is when I open the log and save it directly and as a note, notepad asks to save as rather than just save as normal which does still make me think that its being copied, deleted and copy renamed.

Is there any way that i can get any event to fire when the those switches are made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Action block* of your events run in a different scope and all output produced in them is captured in the [`.Output` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.job.output?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-job-output) of each [`PSEventJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pseventjob?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0). For example, the `.Output` on index `0` would show you all output captured by `Changed` raised events, index `1` for `Created` events and so on:

```bash
$lw.Event[0].Output
```

If you're troubleshooting however, it's much easier to use `Out-Host`, then  the output is sent directly to the console (`Write-Host` would work too):

```bash
$fsaction = {
    $Sender | Format-List | Out-Host
    $EventArgs | Format-List | Out-Host
}
```

Worth noting here, in PowerShell, `$Sender` and `$EventArgs` are [automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables), you don't need to declare them.

I made a few changes to your class too that might help you simplify things:

```bash
class LogWatcher : System.IO.FileSystemWatcher {
    [System.Management.Automation.Job[]] $Event
    [string] $LogName
    [string] $LogFolder

    LogWatcher([string] $folderPath, [string] $fileName) : base($folderPath, $fileName) {
        $this.LogFolder = $folderPath
        $this.LogName = $fileName
        $this.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
        # if you want to target all possibilities, this is easier ;)
        $this.NotifyFilter = [enum]::GetValues([System.IO.NotifyFilters])

        $this.Event = 'Changed', 'Created', 'Deleted', 'Renamed' | ForEach-Object {
            Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $this -EventName $_ -Action {
                $Sender | Format-List | Out-Host
                $EventArgs | Format-List | Out-Host

                # this is so that your watcher can keep track of the new file
                # instead of watching a file that no longer exists
                if ($EventArgs.ChangeType -eq 'Renamed') {
                    $sender.LogName = $sender.Filter = $EventArgs.Name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now for testing, this should work fine in both, Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7+. You should see all events being raised.

```bash
$watcher = [LogWatcher]::new($pwd.Path, 'testingwatcher.txt')

'Creating File...'
Start-Sleep 1
$file = New-Item 'testingwatcher.txt' -Force

'Changing File...'
Start-Sleep 1
$file.LastWriteTime = [datetime]::Today

'Renaming File...'
Start-Sleep 1
$file = $file | Rename-Item -NewName 'ihaveanewname.txt' -PassThru

'Deleting File...'
Start-Sleep 1
$file.Delete()

# Cleanup - probably your class should implement IDisposable ;)
$watcher.Event.Name | Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier { $_ }
```